# Optimize a query using active record rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The DB relation in rails models:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_messages
  has_many :messages
end

Class UserMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
end

Class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_messages
end
```

I want to optimize the following code:

```
ids.each do |id|
  user = User.find_by_id(id)
  unread_count = user.user_messages.where(:folder => user.inbox_id, :read => false).count
  puts "UserID #{id} ---- Unread Message count #{unread_count}"
end
```

Can some tell me how can I optimize the above code using Active record or SQL Query. I basically want to reduce DB queries and time the above code take to complete the loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a left join with a group by and count. Have you tried doing a basic tutorial to sql?

Comment: you should store an `unread_count` column in `users` table to store `unread_count` for each user.

Comment: Thanh I can store the unread_count in users tables because I insert bulk data in user_messages table using this Model.import method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
users = User.where(id: ids).includes(:user_messages)
users.each do |user|
  unread_count = user.user_messages.where(:folder => user.inbox_id, :read => false).count
  puts "UserID #{user.id} ---- Unread Message count #{unread_count}"
end
```

Since you are eager loading `user_messages`, it won't fire any other DB query inside the loop. Only 1 query to fetch user and it's user_messages.

Or you can do something like:

```
user_messages = UserMessage.joins(:user).where('folder = users.inbox_id AND read = false').group(:user_id).count
# user_messages = {1=>10, 2=>19}
# Here keys are user ids and values are no of user_messages for that user

user_messages.each do |user_id,unread_msg_count|
  puts "UserID #{user_id} ---- Unread Message count #{unread_msg_count}"
end
```

PS: I have not tested any code, please comment any error if you have any. And I assumed here `puts "UserID #{ids}` you want to put a single user id and modified my code according to it, since in your code it will print all  the ids `ids`.